# I tried running .box extension file in tesseract but got "read_params_file: Can't open .stderr"

Tags: tesseract

I tried running this code but an error occurred that the parameters couldn't be read:

```
tesseract eng.font-name.exp0.tif eng.font-name.box nobatch box.train .stderr
```

The error was:

> "read_params_file: Can't open .stderr"

Comment: hi tammy. This question needs some improvement. Pleas read [ask] and provide a [mvce].

Answer (score 1):

**Try:-**

```
tesseract eng.font-name.exp0.tif eng.font-name.box nobatch box.train.stderr
```

**Instead:-**

```
tesseract eng.font-name.exp0.tif eng.font-name.box nobatch box.train .stderr
```

Remove the space and try. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You instructed tesseract to read parameters/configuration from file `.stderr`. And tesseract is not able to open it/read from it. I guess it does not exist.